# Fix YAML syntax highlighting in VIM

Tags: vim, regex, syntax

The YAML syntax highlighting in Vim 7.3 isn't great. Putting an apostrophe in a line of text triggers quote highlighting even when there's no quote. The same thing happens in other files sometimes too. I've posted a screenshot below. Is there any way to fix this behavior, or is there a different YAML syntax file I can use that won't trigger this behavior? This occurs in both MacVim and Vim in the Terminal. I'm running v7.3.

Thanks for your help,
Kevin

[image: attached a]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at your vim7.3 installation directory under `syntax/yaml.vim`, roughly line 32:

```
syn region  yamlString      matchgroup=yamlStringDelimiter
                            \ start=+'+ skip=+''+ end=+'+
                            \ contains=yamlSingleEscape
```

if you throw that out, vim wont try to guess that `'` is not the start of a string. the only other way imho would be to change the code so a `'` only count as the start of a string, if the preceding character is a whitespace... but if you dont use `'` as string-quote anyway, just throw out what i mentioned.

Comment: for VIM 7.4 you want to find two lines that start with `syn region yamlFlowString` and comment them out.